# unexpected results while writing to buffer in compute shader

Tags: swift, metal

Here is a simple metal compute shader:

```
kernel void test(uint k [[ thread_position_in_grid ]],
                         device float* a [[buffer(1)]]){
    a[k] = 2;
};
```

On the CPU I access the data like so:

```
let size = floatArray.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: floatArray[0])
metalBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: floatArray, length: size, options: [])
data = metalBuffer.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
```

`floatArray` is all zeros. I dispatch with

```
encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(MTLSize(width:32, height:1, depth:1),
threadsPerThreadgroup: MTLSize(width:32, height:1, depth:1))
```

When the shader has finished I print the contents:

```
print(data[0])
```

Now `data[0]` and `data[1]` both give a value of `2` as expected, but the rest are not `2`. For example `data[2]` is about `1.477`. I feel like I must be making a simple mistake.

Comment: What is `size`, and how are you dispatching the work (threadgroup size and count)?

Comment: Sorry for the omission. I have added the relevant parts to the question.

Comment: Which platform/version is this on (iOS, macOS)? If macOS, is the buffer storage mode `shared` or `managed`? Regardless, how are you ensuring the work is done before you read the results? `waitUntilCompleted()`, or a completion handler closure?

Comment: It is iOS 10.1.1. I realize now there is a flaw in my code that is waiting for the shader to finish. But I don't think this could be the source of my problem. My print command is running in a loop (the `draw` method of the view controller), so I expect that `data[2]` should equal `2` at some point soon after running the program but this does not happen. The value fluctuates a little bit but stays near `1.477`

Comment: I thought the problem might have something to do with converting the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to `UnsafeMutablePointer` so I printed directly from the raw pointer but this had no effect.